# Doctrine2 ArrayType corrupted

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am storing additional user information in a Doctrine2 Array in my Database. My current user count is rapidly growing and some of them manage to get corrupt values into the database (I am using a Rest API via FOSRestBundle).

e.g.:

> a:7:{s:8:"top_team";s:18:"FC Bayern
>   München";s:10:"top_player";s:5:"Eidax";s:9:"flop_team";s:4:"1860";s:7:"one_day";s:13:"Onkel
>   Charlie";s:8:"elevator";s:4:"

As you see the serialized array ends to early. I don't know how my user get this stuff into the database but it happens. Does anybody know a special character or something that breaks the serialize / unserialize of doctrine2?

I have already tried all special characters my keyboard could find, but couldn't manage to break it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data type "string" in the database. Change the type to "text".

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
  */
  protected $xxx;
```